# PHP Nested SOAP tags with class maps

Tags: php, soap

I used [wsdl2php.php](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2php/) to create classes with a class map based on the wsdl.  It generated two classes, one for creating an account and one for name value pairs.

I'm trying to figure out how to use the class(es) to create a soap request.  The soap server is .Net.

Here is the soap request suggested by the CreateAccount.asmx page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateAccount xmlns="https://www.mywsdlsitehere.com/Account">
      <parameters>
        <NameValue>
          <name>string</name>
          <value>string</value>
        </NameValue>
        <NameValue>
          <name>string</name>
          <value>string</value>
        </NameValue>
      </parameters>
    </CreateAccount>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I've tried using several ways of nesting the name and value pairs into the NameValue tags.

Here is my latest, failed attempt:

```
$createaccount->parameters->fullName='Testy Tester';
$createaccount->parameters->userEmail='testy@tester.com';
$createaccount->parameters->accountName='TestyTester';
$createaccount->parameters->password='*****';

class CreateAccount {
  public $parameters; // ArrayOfNameValue
}

class NameValue {
  public $name; // string
  public $value; // string
}

public function CreateAccount(CreateAccount $parameters) {
    return $this->__soapCall('CreateAccount', array($parameters),       array(
            'uri' => 'https://www.mywsdlsitehere.com/Accounting',
            'soapaction' => ''
           )
      );
  }
```

The error I get is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was
>   unable to process request. ---> Value cannot be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating a structure that the service needs.

The service needs a `CreateAccount` object at top level which has a property `parameters`, which is an array, which contains multiple instances of `NameValue` objects.

I'd expect something like this:

```
$create = new CreateAccount();
$create->parameters = array();

$nameValue1 = new NameValue();
$nameValue1->name = "Name1";
$nameValue1->value = "Value1";

$create->parameters[] = $nameValue1;
```

Comment: Thanks Sven.  What would I do for multiple NameValue pairs?  For example, 3 different names and values?  Would I copy $nameValue1's three lines, then add a new line for each $create->parameters[] = $nameValue1?

Comment: I have this now:  `$create = new CreateAccount();
$create->parameters = array();

$nameValue1 = new NameValue();
$nameValue1->name = "Name1";
$nameValue1->value = "Value1";

$create->parameters[] = $nameValue1;

$cr_result = $account->CreateAccount($create);
var_dump($cr_result)`

and I get the following error:
Server was unable to process request. ---> There was an error executing a remote action (There was an error deserializing an object (There is an error in XML document (1, 2). (<HTML xmlns=''> was not expected.)))

Comment: I forgot to mention that $account is an instance of the AccountService class where the soapcall is initiated.  I know it works because I used it for other soap calls such as GetAccount and UsernameAvailable.